Json is not parsing - syntax error- stream analytics
I am trying to parse Json data using azure stream analytics. I am getting the below error.

Syntax errors: Incorrect syntax near duration. Location: line '4', column '5'.

SELECT
duration.value,
duration.count,
duration.1sampledValue,
duration.sum,
duration.mean
FROM input


add the sample data you are using.

The issue seems to be in the column name 1sampledvalue. Check if the column name is correct. If your column name has started with number, make sure it is enclosed with square brackets. Below is the correct query.
SELECT
    duration.value,
    duration.count,
    duration.[1sampledValue]
FROM input


